# C++ cURL JSON save token to file or cookie

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I want to save token from oAUTH2 login to file or cookie, but when I try to save it to file I get msg from cURL : [response when I try to save data to memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL2lu.png) but when I comment this line:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
```

Then console shows me normal JSON response from server with token

Here is my code:

```cpp
chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char* curlErrStr = (char*)malloc(CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_slist* httpHeaders = NULL;
if(curl) 
{
struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

curl_slist_append(headers, "HOST: xxx");
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");   
curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "xx");
/* Now specify the POST data */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=xxx&password=xxx");

/* get it! */

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

/* check for errors */
if (res != CURLE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
}
else {

    printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk.size);
}
    
ofstream oplik;
oplik.open("get_token.json");
oplik << chunk.memory;
oplik.close();
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
if (chunk.memory)
    free(chunk.memory);
curl_global_cleanup();
```

So I think I should save it to cookie, am I right?

Maybe some sample code how to save it to cookie?

Comment: Doesn't seem like you're using `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` correctly https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html

Comment: it works for my in other case, so thats why i try to use it here too

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code and it works :) big thanks to Alan Birtles

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
```